# How to prove this relation's transitivity

Tags: discrete-mathematics, relations

So i have to prove that the relation $\leq$ is a partial order on N, where   $≤$   is deﬁned as follows:

$\forall(m_{\in\mathbb N})(n_{\in\mathbb N}) : (n\leq m)\iff (\exists (k_{\in N})  n+k=m)$.

For this one I do understand why it is Antisymmetric and reflexive, but I don't completely understand how it's transitive. For a transitive relation $R$, if $(a,b)\in R$ and $(b,c)\in R$ , then $a$ should also be in a relation with $c$, I just don't know how to prove it on this exact example

Comment: Suppose $a\le b$ and $b le c$, then there are natural numbers $k_1$ and $k_2$ such that $a+k_1=b$ and $b+k_2=c$. So $a+(k_1+k_2)=c$, by definition $a\le c$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $l\leq n$ and $n\leq m$.

Then $r,s\in\mathbb N$ exist with $l+r=n$ and $n+s=m$.

From this we conclude directly that: $$l+(r+s)=(l+r)+s=n+s=m$$ and this of course with $r+s\in\mathbb N$ so that the conclusion $l\leq m$ is justified.